# Serving .scss files on rails development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using RubyMine together with a ruby/rails project where .scss files are joined to one applcation.scss and then compiled to one application.css file which is served.

I would like to serve the .scss file too, but just in the development so I will be able to edit the .scss file in chrome dev tools without the need to refresh and won't need to go back to the ruby mine to update the .scss file.

How do I serve the application.scss too then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Less/Sass debugging in Chrome Dev Tools/Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865302/less-sass-debugging-in-chrome-dev-tools-firebug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4, you can install and follow the instructions for the [sass-rails-source-maps gem](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps). Then you should be able to see/edit .scss files in Chrome's web inspector.